# Error when updating eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I click update in eclipse and I get an error, it's because I updated eclipse more than once. Is there any way to fix eclipse and have the ability to use update?

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jem/osgi.bundle/2.0.202.v200810282000
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jem.workbench/osgi.bundle/2.0.102.v200810230530
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jpt.core/osgi.bundle/2.1.0.v200812160210
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jpt.doc.user/osgi.bundle/1.0.300.v200812110000
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jpt.eclipselink.core/osgi.bundle/1.1.0.v200812110000
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jpt.eclipselink.core.ddlgen/osgi.bundle/1.0.100.v200811030000
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jpt.eclipselink.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/2.1.0.v200812180210-318Y9oA55S8_795555
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jpt.eclipselink.ui/osgi.bundle/1.1.0.v200812100000
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jpt.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/2.1.0.v200812180210-7979AgCYQCD4IRJdCEDC
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jpt.ui/osgi.bundle/2.1.0.v200812080000
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.common.frameworks/osgi.bundle/1.1.201.v200810161330
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.ejb.doc.user/osgi.bundle/1.1.100.v200810092245
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.ejb.ui/osgi.bundle/1.1.203.v200810010400
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_core.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/3.0.3.v200810010400-42E_4_kE77c_FAP7X99
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_ui.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/3.0.3.v200810010400-7Y7BFSrEPOwQPnUuwhYV60NEQtTn
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_userdoc.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/3.0.3.v200810131754-52EFBAgI99mAV9oGIHb
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst/org.eclipse.update.feature/3.0.3.v200809250443-7U-9-9LJGGJebgG8HYgv5FBP0NUr
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee/osgi.bundle/1.1.204.v200811130630
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.core/osgi.bundle/1.1.202.v200811111600
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb/osgi.bundle/1.1.203.v200811060500
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.jca/osgi.bundle/1.1.203.v200811060900
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.navigator.ui/osgi.bundle/1.1.202.v200810222000
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ui/osgi.bundle/1.1.204.v200811041823
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web/osgi.bundle/1.1.202.v200811060500
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.webservice.ui/osgi.bundle/1.1.201.v200811062130
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.jee/osgi.bundle/1.0.102.v200811060500
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.jee.ejb/osgi.bundle/1.0.102.v200810230722
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui/osgi.bundle/1.0.103.v200811131900
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.jee.web/osgi.bundle/1.0.101.v200810230738
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core/osgi.bundle/1.2.120.v200810301812
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui/osgi.bundle/1.1.311.v200810210016
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.server.core/osgi.bundle/1.1.2.v20080930
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core/osgi.bundle/1.1.104.v20081006
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.server_adapters.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/3.0.3.v20081006b-787KEKFDUUEFDFrPa7AMQ
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.server_core.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/3.0.3.v20080930b-377Ap9oA55S5N_C35AC
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.server_ui.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/3.0.3.v20081001-79-EDn9wKSZRCCNQMfVnIG8BHD
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui/osgi.bundle/1.1.203.v200810222000
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.web_core.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/3.0.3.v200810020322-7M7AEX2EFp_acwkiuz-bTpl
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.web_ui.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/3.0.3.v200810020322-7E4EArDgvY1en0e_Bm21-ljvz00c
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis.consumption.core/osgi.bundle/1.0.306.v200810082309
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis.consumption.ui/osgi.bundle/1.0.305.v200809301934
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.core/osgi.bundle/1.0.104.v200810151442
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2tools.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/1.0.2.v200810151341-77-E_ECYQCD4FdMjLXVW
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.ws.consumption/osgi.bundle/1.0.306.v200810012118
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.ws.consumption.ui/osgi.bundle/1.1.3.v200810012118
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.ws.consumption.ui.doc.user/osgi.bundle/1.0.500.v200810082020
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.ws.creation.ui/osgi.bundle/1.0.307.v200810012118
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.command.env/osgi.bundle/1.0.307.v200810082309
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.common.emf/osgi.bundle/1.1.203.v200811022047
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.common.emfworkbench.integration/osgi.bundle/1.1.202.v200811131900
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks/osgi.bundle/1.1.201.v200811060900
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.ui/osgi.bundle/1.1.201.v200810020330
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore/osgi.bundle/1.1.204.v200811062000
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core/osgi.bundle/1.3.4.v200810151458
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.common.ui/osgi.bundle/1.1.302.v200810160107
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.common_core.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/3.0.3.v200809301154-7C7_EVIE_EkMNrTtU7X4h2
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.common_ui.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/3.0.3.v200809301154-7C78ELcE8VrRVouGlyiT4DsUuV8Y
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst/org.eclipse.update.feature/3.0.3.v200809250443-7A-8i8Qqcz0FaVgjXSD6brFQN64Z
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.html.core/osgi.bundle/1.1.203.v200810291731
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.html.ui/osgi.bundle/1.0.302.v200810291731
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core/osgi.bundle/1.0.103.v200811042159
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.doc/osgi.bundle/1.0.103.v200810081720
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/1.0.3.v200810020426-6-E73BcMAAwFIFUHpRJ
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.support.firefox/osgi.bundle/1.0.103.v200810021840
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.support.ie/osgi.bundle/1.0.103.v200810021840
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui/osgi.bundle/1.0.103.v200810301820
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.web.core/osgi.bundle/1.0.103.v200810021840
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.web.support.jsp/osgi.bundle/1.0.103.v200810081720
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.web.ui/osgi.bundle/1.0.103.v200810021840
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.server.core/osgi.bundle/1.1.2.v20081020
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.server.ui/osgi.bundle/1.1.3.v20080930
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user/osgi.bundle/1.1.100.v200810082048
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.server_core.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/3.0.3.v20080930b-20Al8s733I48671256
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.server_ui.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/3.0.3.v20080930b-791CO9vESQmvbHKYENNI76CH
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.server_userdoc.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/3.0.100.v200810082053-108Y7w311921193159
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui/osgi.bundle/1.1.3.v200810301815
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.validation/osgi.bundle/1.2.3.v200811101716
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.validation.ui/osgi.bundle/1.2.2.v200810221105
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.web/osgi.bundle/1.1.205.v200811132030
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.web_core.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/3.0.3.v200810010400-7G2EAsAM214fK_RKaovH35PiPtaH
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/3.0.3.v200810010400-7R0EOzE8Ks9uCz0nqrQF6yCFSQyI
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.ws.explorer/osgi.bundle/1.0.308.v200811062250
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.ws_core.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/3.0.3.v200810012109-7H7QECgED69XqKg9nufm2_7C5J
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.ws_ui.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/3.0.3.v200810012109-7E2EFVC-2f_FDJhnGKZmULIbsTaU
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.ws_userdoc.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/3.0.2.v200810081944-34EDe9oA55S6I5S8KCS
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.ws_wsdl14.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/1.4.1.v200809302010-13-7w311917141518
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.ws_wsdl15.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/1.5.2.v200809302010-1407w311917141519
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.wsdl/osgi.bundle/1.1.202.v200809291819
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.wsdl.ui/osgi.bundle/1.2.103.v200810301738
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.wsdl.ui.doc.user/osgi.bundle/1.0.501.v200810081958
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.xml.core/osgi.bundle/1.1.306.v200810210016
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui/osgi.bundle/1.0.420.v200810220345
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.xml_core.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/3.0.3.v200810021802-7A7NEH0E7QYGHNIxPlGgVY
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/3.0.3.v200809292000-7F2ENZCwum8U9-9yPhHnPkSb2VAc
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.xml_userdoc.feature/org.eclipse.update.feature/3.0.3.v200810090336-40EJs_kE77c8P_TALGS
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.xmleditor.doc.user/osgi.bundle/1.0.500.v200810081958
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.xsd.core/osgi.bundle/1.1.302.v200810020300
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.xsd.ui/osgi.bundle/1.2.104.v200810020602
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jpt.db/osgi.bundle/1.2.0.v200810300000
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jpt.db.ui/osgi.bundle/1.1.0.v200808210000
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jpt.gen/osgi.bundle/1.2.0.v200810080000
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jpt.utility/osgi.bundle/1.3.0.v200811030000
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.ws/osgi.bundle/1.0.306.v200810020426
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.consumption.core/osgi.bundle/1.0.104.v200810151442
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.creation.core/osgi.bundle/1.0.104.v200810151442
```

Comment: Thanks for the "accepted status". Could you tell us what advice/workaround did the trick in your case ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

What version of eclipse are you using ?

It has been [fixed in 3.4.1](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=251716), but in your case, it could be [this bug instead](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=236437).

> It turns out the cause is one or more artifact repositories being lost from the list of known repositories.
>
> The workaround is to remove the repository from the list and add it back again. This restores the missing artifact repository.

---

A possible workaround in eclipse 3.4.1:

1. export the update site listing to `bookmarks.xml` file (`Software Updates->Manage sites->Export`)
2. stop eclipse
3. **remove `configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.*.prefs` files**
   (Note, as mentioned by [Fredrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207764/fredrik) in the comments, for Eclipse3.5+, this would be:
   `p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\.settings`
   `p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profileRegistry\SDKProfile.profile\.data\.setti‌​ngs`)
4. start eclipse
5. import the `bookmarks.xml` file (`Software Updates->Manage sites->Import`) that was exported in step 1

As mentioned by [mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30453/mark) (author of this question) in the comments of this answer, that workaround was a solution for his problem.

---

Other advice:

> [...] the solution is always to append a trailing `'/'` to *all* repository URLs in my P2 UI.
> My feeling is that this error is caused by a failure to construct a viable URL to a repo resource. The code in question is not inspecting the URL string from the UI and is assuming a trailing '/' resulting in a 404

This last solution is confirmed working in Eclipse Indigo and Juno (below in the comments).

Comment: i used the "remove .. org.eclipse.equinox.p2 ..."

Comment: @Hamidam: with which version of Eclipse and with what kind of error message (the same ones than the OP's question?). Maybe a fresh installation might be an easier path.

Comment: For Eclipse 3.5 and later the paths in #3 should be p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\.settings 
p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profileRegistry\SDKProfile.profile\.data\.settings
Right?

Comment: @Fredrik: I think you are right. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: In 4.2 Juno adding a / to all repos fixed it for me.

Comment: In Indigo adding a / to all repos fixed it for me.

Answer (score 11):

Yet another solution -

Instead exporting all managed sites and importing them back,
click on 'edit' on each checked site and add '//' at the end

If you just add a '/' it says duplicate site therefore the '//'

How a small bug in a huge carefully architected application
can be so hard to debug yet simple to solve

Comment: Worked for me for Spring Tool Suite 4.2.2. I only had to add a double slash at the end of the Spring repo, however it now added another identical spring repo I see. As long as it works I suppose...

Answer (score 3):

*Though this question is answered a long back, wanted to share my experience thinking that it may save some one' day :)*

Some times it could also be possible due to the incorrect proxy settings. In my case (Eclipse 3.6/Helios), Eclipse preference file `$ECLIPSE_HOME$/configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.core.net.prefs` is having proxy details,

```
proxyData/HTTP/hasAuth=true
systemProxiesEnabled=true
proxyData/HTTP/host=proxy.domain.net
org.eclipse.core.net.hasMigrated=true
eclipse.preferences.version=1
proxiesEnabled=true
proxyData/HTTP/port=9119
nonProxiedHosts=
```

When I deleted the file after closing the Eclipse, then onwards I m able to download the plugins

Comment: This is one possible reason and as answered by others there are many others reasons causing the said problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Eclipse Helios (3.6) on Ubuntu 64 bits.

Removing

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/helios

from the "Available Software Sites" in Eclipse, and adding it again did the fix.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (well similar as I was just trying to install subclipse). VonC's tip "Other advice" did it for me.

1. Export sites to bookmarks.xml
2. Edit this file and append a forward slash at the end of every URL where it is missing.
3. Delete all sites
4. Re-import edited bookmarks.xml
5. Sigh with relief as it works.

Answer (score 1):

The backslash thing in the exported bookmarks file fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
After exporting and importing bookmarks, the problem did not get resolved.
but I started getting error 'Connection refused'.

On further thoughts I found that my antivirus is not allowing eclipse to talk to internet. Disabling antivirus made it work.

Sandeep Jindal

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem over the last couple months, but ignored it until I really needed PyDev to work on my laptop today.

I tried the solutions above to no avail and then I found something odd:

In (Window->Preferences->Install/Update->Available Software) I noticed that the box for 'PyDev Update Site' AND another one right below it with the location 'file:/updates' were both checked, causing a duplicate of most or all update URLs.  After un-checking the box with the location 'file:/updates' I was able to update from (Help->Check for Updates) which then successfully installed the latest version of PyDev.

This solution might not be applicable to PyDev updates alone and could hopefully help others with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, I diabled my ZoneAlarm Firewall, and it connected OK!

Is there some kind of rule I need to add into my firewall to stop it blocking eclipse? It never used to do this, everything was working find until last week (Sept 25th (ish) 2012)

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered a similar problem I add the following repository to my available update site.  http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4/.

Make sure the slash in at the end of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution for this problem, that I tested, on https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-websphere-mq-explorer/login-warning, just install "Eclipse Tests, Examples, and Extras" -> "Eclipse 2.0 Style Plugin Support" from The Eclipse Project Updates repository

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was caused by having **two update sites for STS of which one one obsolote and not available any more**. Both were present and checked in Install/Available Software Sites.

Solution was simple: unchecking the site that was not available. Available update sites for sts are listed here: https://spring.io/tools/sts/all.