# Trying to configure eclipse for android development

Tags: android, eclipse

i have been trying to configure eclispe to work with the ADT plugin to no avail. The android tutorials also haven't helped.
I have added the relevant site needed for new software install in the SDK
I get this error.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.xml,1.3.4.v201005080400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.xerces,2.9.0.v201005080400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.xml.resolver,1.2.0.v201005080400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.xml.serializer,2.7.1.v201005080400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.draw2d,3.6.2.v20110128-0100
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.common,2.6.0.v20100914-1218
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore,2.6.1.v20100914-1218
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change,2.5.1.v20100907-1643
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi,2.5.0.v20100521-1846
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.edit,2.6.0.v20100914-1218
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef,3.6.2.v20110110-2020
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem.util,2.1.3.v201012070000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.core,1.2.0.v200908252030
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.emf,1.2.3.v201012100400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.emfworkbench.integration,1.2.3.v201012020600
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.environment,1.0.400.v200912181832
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks,1.2.0.v201003040800
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core,1.4.102.v201008170019
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.ui,1.1.500.v200911190730
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.uriresolver,1.1.401.v201004280700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.core,1.1.504.v201102160550
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui,1.2.3.v201102102045
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.validation,1.2.201.v201101270100
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xml.core,1.1.503.v201102102045
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui,1.1.103.v201101122108
```

HELP!!!!!!!!

Comment: Did you install the SDK starter package first as described [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html)? What OS and Eclipse versions are you using?

Comment: Vista
Eclipse Classic 3.6.2, Also i downloaded the zipped SDK....after which i felt the .exe would help so i downloaded it tried to run it but it says it cant find my JDK and JRE is insufficient...but i wrote and ran java code in this same IDE...

Comment: can you post the link here from where you are trying to download the software,
I have a solution in case nothing helps you. Just download the contents from the link to your computer and then goto install new software and add a link to your folder where you downloaded the contents, be sure to add the suffix "files:///" eg "files:///c:/users/download/yourFolder"

Answer (score 1):

Are you on Windows 7/Vista?  You need to have Admin Privileges to install the SDK Components.

ALso it might be that your site list is corrupted/bad.
[Similar Post on SOF with similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511367/error-when-updating-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are running on a 64-bit system and have 64-bit Java installed. For reasons I can't fathom, you need to have both 32-bit and 64-bit Java installed. Only then should you run the SDK starter package and then install the ADT plugin for Eclipse. (If you already installed the plugin, remove it before starting all this.)